# Extent: Add Class name to Test Success

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I want to add Test Class Name and Method Name into extent report as highlight in the picture. I want to change the loginInvalid to ClassName::Method name. I tried with following but no success.

```
@Override
    public synchronized void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println(result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " passed!");
        test.get().pass(result.getTestContext().getClass().getName() + " Test passed");
    }
```

[image: Extent Report]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
String feature = result.getMethod().getRealClass().getName() + ":" + result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        ExtentTest extentTest = extent.createTest(feature, result.getMethod().getDescription());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the TestLisener on metod *onTestSuccess* you can create a label

```
extentTest.debug(MarkupHelper.createLabel(iTestResult.getMethod().getQualifiedName(), ExtentColor.TRANSPARENT));
```

This will return the full path

```
testCases.Name1.Name2.Scenario_1.TestCase_1
```

You can split them by "."